# Orange lines coming from rocket engine nozzle?

Tags: rockets, engines, plume

This image of a test-fire of the RS-88 ethanol/LOX engine from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-88). It is apparent that there are these orange lines extending from inside the nozzle into the plume. What is it, and why is this phenomenon occuring?

[image]

Comment: It looks like hot gas jets with some glowing carbon dust or soot, therefore the intensive orange light. Burning ethanol oxygen rich gives a blue flame. So the orange lines may be fuel rich areas. The injector for ethanol and LOX may be the reason for the orange lines.

Comment: Cool picture in any case.

Comment: @Uwe Is this due to the type of injector?

Comment: @uhoh fixed it.

Comment: Some engines inject extra fuel at the sides of the nozzle to provide thrust vectoring without moving the engine and/or nozzle. The three luminescent streams look so similar to each other and potentially evenly spaced (every 120°?) that this might be a possibility. A quick check didn't turn up anything though.

Comment: The RS-88 is not a full flow engine and there is not a visible bypass exhaust. I’m assuming the white stream under the engine is water, it seems too far back to be a bypass. Perhaps they eject the bypass from the preburners into the nozzle. It would explain the near perfect symmetry.