# What engine cycle does the RS-88 and its hypergol derivative use?

Tags: engines, engine-design

A comment on this question [Orange lines coming from rocket engine nozzle?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/60574/orange-lines-coming-from-rocket-engine-nozzle) stated in part

> The RS-88 is not a full flow engine and there is not a visible bypass exhaust. ... Perhaps they eject the bypass from the preburners into the nozzle.

What engine cycle does this engine use? I would be surprised if it has preburners, but I could not find any information on it. This [paper](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20050237017/downloads/20050237017.pdf) doesn't say.  This Rocketdyne [press release](https://www.rocket.com/article/aerojet-rocketdyne-successfully-tests-engine-made-entirely-additive-manufacturing) about its BANTAM precursor says it's based on the Atlas sustainer engine, which was a gas generator cycle, but nothing about the RS-88 itself.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I researched this for several minutes and was unable to find an answer. Good question though. @organic marble

Comment: Incomplete answer, but I found that the wikipedia page on the RS-88 is categorized in ["List of engines using the pressure-fed cycle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Rocket_engines_using_the_pressure-fed_cycle) and this (paywalled) paper about the RS-88 which may help: https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/abs/10.2514/6.2005-4422

Comment: @fasterthanlight Good info. I assumed that at least the abort motor variant would be pressure-fed for reliability, but everything I could find just talked about the thrust chamber.

Comment: Unfortunately, the supporting information for this engine as pressure-fed is a little spotty, citation links do not mention anything about the engine being so.